# how to create another sheet while write data using fputcsv in php

Tags: php, fputcsv

I am using fputcsv for write  data. It is working fine. what i need is i need to create another sheet like any name and i need to write data on that. How to do that? Please guide. I am not familiar with this.
This is my code.

```
$filename = date("Y-m-d").".csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'a');
$yetToaproveFields = array('job_no'=>'Job Number',
                         'revisioncycle'=> 'Revision Cycle',
                         'version'=>'Version',
                         'is_approved'=>'Approved Status'
);

fputcsv($fp, $yetToaproveFields);

$notApproveArr = array();
$notApprovedValues = self::getNotApprovedJobs($_REQUEST);
foreach ($notApprovedValues as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value['is_approved'] == 1)
        $value['is_approved'] = 'No';
    fputcsv($fp, $value);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

CSV doesn't support multiple sheets, it's a simple text file. To use sheets, you should use an Excel extension, such as [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

Comment: using by this library PHPEXcel can i generate .csv file

Comment: Yes you can, but, once again, CSV **does not support** multiple sheets.

Comment: C i just explain my task. Initially someone created one file with the extension of .csv.  and they write data using fputcsv.What i need to do is I have to create another sheet with the same file. So if i use PHPExcel means should i change previously used fputcsv commands also?

Comment: Yep, you must use PHPExcel to generate your whole file (both sheets).

Comment: I have used PHPEXcel for creating sheets. The problem is row height and width is too small. How to set height and width?

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($headerCol, $headerRow, $headerValue);

Comment: using by above method I'm writing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

CSV is a very simple data file format. It doesn't support spreadsheet features like styling or multiple worksheets. If you want multiple worksheets, then you need to use a spreadsheet file format like BIFF (`.xls`), OfficeOpenXML (`.xlsx`) or OASIS (`.ods`)

Comment: can i use fputcsv after create new sheet?

Comment: No, you can't use multiple sheets with CSV. You have to use a whole different PHP extension, which won't create a `.csv` file, but a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer Sir.